# Magento 1.9 translations not working

Tags: magento, csv, magento-1.9

I have a weird problem. I made some translations for my Magento shop (using `.csv` files) and my translation for `Add to Wishlist` suddenly disappeared.

I've not change anything in `.csv` files since this translation working and in `.csv` translation is correct.

In table `core_translation` I haven't got any translation for this. Labels in code are not changed.

Where else can store magento translation?

P.S. `Reindex` store and clear `Cache` didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You have put the `csv` file inside `module` folder or `theme` folder?

The priority order of translation is

1. from `database`
2. from `theme`
3. from `module`

So if the translation entry is present both in module and the theme folder, the module entry will be replaced by the theme entry

Comment: Yes, I know that. I resolved my problem by replace $this->__('Add to Wishlist') by Mage::helper('core')->__('Add to Wishlist').

Problem is weird because Magento translate 'Add to Wishlist' to word which don't exist in databese, theme or code. But thanks for priority list :) That will be helpfull :)